# AngularJS view doesn't update when replacing value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="skype" ng-change="checkInput('skype')">
```

the function is:

```
$scope.checkInput = function(value) {
    var string = $scope[value],
        pattern = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;

    string = string.replace(pattern, '');
}
```

Now the console.log shows, that the string replaced successfully, however the view doesn't update.
The strangest part is when using substring the view updates!

```
string = string.substring(0, 10);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: No idea but -- this is a bit unorthodox -- add a last line to your function that says `$scope.$apply();`.

Comment: $scope.$apply() needs when you are working on third parties libraries.

Comment: replace in your checkInput  function  var string = $scope[value] by  var string =value; and then try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not setting any value to scope in order to angular can watch and react on that, your function is doing something but never setting value to scope.

```
$scope.checkInput = function(value) {
    var string = $scope[value],
        pattern = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;

    $scope.skype = string.replace(pattern, '');
}
```

Comment: Jorawar Singh, thank you, that's exactly what I needed. What about substring? Why does it work?

Comment: you are replacing the sting like string = string.substring(0, 10); and that's correct but you were not setting it to scope. 
var i = 10;
10 = 5;
now i is 5. you have changed the original value.